# Double clicking detected with jquery on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div like so

```js
$('.btn-group label').unbind().click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  var checked = $(this).find('input').prop('checked');
  console.log(checked);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group pull-left" data-toggle="buttons" style="margin-right: 10px;">
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
     <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" class="selective-growth"> Expand from X
   </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
     <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" class="switch-color"> Switch Color
   </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
     <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" class="perspective"> Maintain Perspective 
   </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
     <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" class="invert"> Invert 
   </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
     <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" class="select-color"> Select Colors 
   </label>
</div>
```

which has a bug, when I check the console result for a click I get two results `false` and `true` from this jquery function

how can I log only the valid one which is true?

On jsfiddle it's working however without double logging https://jsfiddle.net/8wtLc8b6/

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue.

Comment: You are print the result in console whether the checkbox is checked or not. that's why it return true and false in console..

Comment: @bugwheels94 I also created a jsfiddle and it's not logging twice, is there a way to notice only the click?

Comment: adding e.preventDefault(); fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Do with [`change`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwis7_ChucfVAhWKKo8KHb-FBOoQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FEvents%2Fchange&usg=AFQjCNGC0uF517WZTEvyIJw9Gg56ihDEkg) event  instead of `click`

```js
$('.btn-group label').change(function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  var checked = $(this).find('input').prop('checked');
  console.log(checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group pull-left" data-toggle="buttons" style="margin-right: 10px;">
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" class="selective-growth"> Expand from X
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" class="switch-color"> Switch Color
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" class="perspective"> Maintain Perspective 
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" class="invert"> Invert 
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" class="select-color"> Select Colors 
  </label>
</div>
```

**Why?**

Change event run after the changes append in input

```js
$('.btn-group label').change(function(){
console.log('change') //its run only on completely changed
}).click(function(e) {
  console.log('click'); //its run before and after changing
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group pull-left" data-toggle="buttons" style="margin-right: 10px;">
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" class="selective-growth"> Expand from X
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" class="switch-color"> Switch Color
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" class="perspective"> Maintain Perspective 
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" class="invert"> Invert 
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" class="select-color"> Select Colors 
  </label>
</div>
```